# Validação campo javascript com Split

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu preciso fazer uma validação javascript, que pega quantos são preenchidos, a máscara é desta forma: 000,000,000,000
etc, no caso ele deveria pegar 4, pois é a sequência de 4, cada 000 conta um, o usuário vai preencher tipo: 030,050,060 etc
para comparar com o número de pagamentos.

Estou fazendo assim, porém eu preciso que ele pegue a quantidade e não os valores:

```
 var str = $("#FormaCalculosVencimentos").val();
    var arr = str.split(",");
    alert(arr);
```

Comment: Mas se `arr` é um *array*, não basta pegar `arr.length`?

Comment: Isso mesmo rs, deu certinho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função split vai criar um array. Após, você pode utilizar a função length para obter o tamanho da sua variavel arr.

```
var str = $("#FormaCalculosVencimentos").val();
var arr = str.split(",");
alert(arr.length);
```